# google play services not supported for Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-play

I'm developing an app on a PCB board wich has installed some kind of custom android v2.3.7.

I need to run the GoogleMaps. I've done all that is supposed that must be done (created a key, imported google-play-services_lib, downloaded GooglePlayServices from SDk...) but when runing it, shows the next message:

```
Google Play services, which some of your applications rely on, 
is not supported by your device. Please contact the manufacturer for assistance.
```

So, what must I do to make GoogleMaps running?

**UPDATE--**

Manifest file:

```
<manifest
    ...

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="(key)" />
    ...

    <application
    ...

        <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
```

Comment: What you have done so far post your Manifest file code

Comment: @shylendra added the manifest code

Comment: Are you running it in real device or emulator?

Comment: "I'm developing an app on a PCB board wich has installed some kind of custom android v2.3.7"

Comment: The custom Android clearly dose not include Google Play Services.  You need to sideload them or find an alternative mapping library e.g. something OSM based like osmdroid should be workable.